I will be right back as soon as "it is done" VS "it will be done"

I will be right back as soon as it is done.
I will be right back as soon as it will be done.

I've heard the first sentence most of the time, but not the other one.
Why? Is there something wrong with the second sentence?
can we not use the future tense in this case?

The phrase "as soon as", used in this type of context, is a way of making a conditional statement that something will happen at the same time or a very short time after something else happens.
In your example, the condition is when "it" is done. 'Done' is in the past tense. So, you are saying that something will happen after something else has finished - either immediately, or a short time after. The condition will not be met before it is done, so you cannot speak about that event in the future tense.

"I will be back as soon as I finish my work" now we are not using anything Past tense. then my question remains the same why do we use present tense here?

I will be back as soon as I have finished my work is also fine, and in practice means exactly the same, so it's just a stylistic choice. But neither of I will be back as soon as I will finish / will have finished my work are valid.

@hwkal you're right, "finish" is not the past tense, yet it means to complete something. The condition of the statement only applies when it is over, so even when you phrase it in that tense it makes no sense if you use the future tense for the condition.
